# How to resolve this loader issue in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, loader

I wanted to use this popup component from [GitHub](https://github.com/RafaelAugustoS/react-native-popup-ui)

I installed it using npm (I don't know how to do it otherwise).
I imported it to my App.js

```
import { Root, Popup } from 'popup-ui'
```

After importing it, I get this message:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'popup-ui'.
>
> 'c:/Repos/Budgeteer/node_modules/popup-ui/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm install @types/popup-ui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module'popup-ui';
>
> `ts(7016)

@types/popup-ui does not exist. I got no idea what declaration means (total noob here). And I looked up ts(7016), and again I couldn't figure out what to do exactly, being a beginner.

When compiling, I get this issue:

> C:/Repos/Budgeteer/node_modules/popup-ui/src/basic/Popup/index.js 10:1
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:1)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
>
> See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

the error comes with this piece of code:

```
|   static popupInstance
| 
>   static show({ ...config }) {"
|       this.popupInstance.start(config)
|   }
```

I took a look at the link and read up on loaders, but I got no idea what type of loader I need to install, how to install it or how to edit that webpack file. I can't even seem to find it.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. But please try to make it as detailed as possible, because I'm new to all of this.

Also, I'm using React Native with Expo if that matters.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If webpack is running `tsc` (the Typescript compiler) and it's complaining about a `.d.ts`, that's weird.  If Webpack is saying "I don't have a loader defined for .d.ts files", that means something is trying to `require` a .d.ts, which should never happen.

I've had this problem when people have a broad Context defined, either via `require.context(/too-many-files.*\.ts/)`, or   `require("/some/path/" + fileName)`.  Webpack will try to statically analyze the latter statement, and treat (more or less) as `require.context(/\/some\/path\/.*/)`

Either way you wind up with it grabbing `.d.ts` files when it shouldn't.  If you can fix the `require` / `require.context` so it excludes the typings, do that.  If you can't, add a rule like `{test: /\.d\.ts$/, use: "null-loader"}`